# How to get key and value of array json in python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a example array json:

```
[
  {
   'Clothes':[
               {
                 'id': '32705111', 
                 'describes': 'no problem'
               }
             ]
  },
  {
   'Dress':[
               {
                 'id': '32705111', 
                 'describes': 'no outfit'
               }
           ]
  }
]
```

Expected: I want to get each array by PyThon with name and all array element, example 'Clothes' and 'Dress' are name of one array

```
Clothes[{'id': '32705111','describes': 'no problem'}], Dress[{'id': '32705111', 'describes': 'no outfit'}]
```

Please help me about this my problem. Thank you so much and love you!!!!

Comment: It's best to show your attempted at a problem when asking a question. Can you post your current code along with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, I guess this is what you are looking for

```
new_lst = []

for i in json_array:
    for name, array in i.items():
       value = ''.join(str(array))
       result = name+value
       new_lst.append(result)

print(new_lst)
```

Output -

```
["Clothes[{'id': '32705111', 'describes': 'no problem'}]", "Dress[{'id': '32705111', 'describes': 'no outfit'}]"]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it took me a lot of time on this problem and you helped me out.  Once again, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
json_arr = [
  {
   'Clothes': [
               {
                 'id': '32705111',
                 'describes': 'no problem'
               }
             ]
  },
  {
   'Dress': [
               {
                 'id': '32705111',
                 'describes': 'no outfit'
               }
           ]
  }
]

for d in json_arr:
    for name, array in d.items():
        globals()[name] = array
```

Comment: Thank you very much about this code but it is no good for my problem.